# What is the second argument in QgsProcessingUtils.mapLayerFromString()?

Tags: python, python-3.x, gis, qgis, pyqgis

I'm currently trying to select a layer. In Qgis 2, this was done by doing

```
from qgis import processing
lyrConsumer = processing.getObject('contours-iris-2014')
```

But now, the documentation says that I have to use QgsProcessingUtils.mapLayerFromString() in Qgis3. Apparently, I need to put a second argument now, as I get this error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\OSGEO4~1\apps\Python37\lib\code.py", line 90, in runcode
    exec(code, self.locals)
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: QgsProcessingUtils.mapLayerFromString(): not enough arguments
```

What is the second argument?

Comment: Have you looked at [the documentation](https://qgis.org/pyqgis/3.0/core/Processing/QgsProcessingUtils.html#qgis.core.QgsProcessingUtils.mapLayerFromString)?

Comment: Yeah, I looked it up and it says that the second argument is the context. I am new to Qgis and I don’t know if the “context” is a file path, a file or a python class.

Comment: Have you given my answer a try?

Answer (score 1):

The second parameter is a `QgsProcessingContext()`, which lets the algorithm know what is the context in which it will run.

You can set it in this way:

```
context = QgsProcessingContext()
context.setProject(QgsProject.instance())
QgsProcessingUtils.mapLayerFromString('my_layer', context)
```

---

However, since you said you're trying to select a layer, if you're attempting to get a layer from the QGIS layer tree, you can have a look at [Getting layer by name in PyQGIS?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/136879/4972).

Answer (score -3):

Visit [QGIS API Documentation](https://qgis.org/api/classQgsProcessingUtils.html) you will find the answer.